# Unable to create oracle table using java code

Tags: java, sql, oracle

```
try {
    String strQry= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ERROR_DETAIL (\"SNO\"NUMBER(16,0),\"TABLE_NAME\"  VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),\"ERROR_DESC\" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),\"XCOORDINATE\" FLOAT(126),\"YCOORDINATE\" FLOAT(126),\"STATUS\"  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),\"COMMENT\" Varchar2(255 Byte),PRIMARY KEY (\"TABLE_NAME\", \"ERROR_DESC\") ENABLE);";
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    stmt.execute(strQry);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this code giving Error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

but same query working properly in oracle

Comment: Possible duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477099/create-table-if-not-exists-how-to-check-the-schema-too

Comment: [IF NOT EXISTS -DDL- doesn't exist in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618179/is-there-something-like-if-not-exist-create-sequence-in-oracle-sql). You'll have to either check if the object exists beforehand using the dictionary tables OR catch the appropriate error.

Comment: Is it really that hard to check the correct syntax in the manual?

Answer (score 0):

Print the content of your `strQry` variable, and you'll see that it's not valid:

- you don't need double quotes around column names
- you should have a space between each column name and its type
- you shouldn't have a semi-colon at the end of the query

Moreover, I think you should use `executeUpdate()` and not `execute()`.

Comment: Now  ihave done change according to you but still not working.  String strQry= "CREATE TABLE ERROR_DETAIL (SNO NUMBER(16,0),TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),ERROR_DESC VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),XCOORDINATE FLOAT(126),YCOORDINATE FLOAT(126),STATUS VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),COMMENT Varchar2(255 Byte),PRIMARY KEY (TABLE_NAME, ERROR_DESC) ENABLE)";   Now error changes java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Comment: COMMENT is not a valid column name. Choose another name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below piece of code.

```
try {
    String strQry= " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ERROR_DETAIL (SNO NUMBER(16,0),TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),ERROR_DESC VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),XCOORDINATE FLOAT(126),YCOORDINATE FLOAT(126),STATUS VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),COMMENT Varchar2(255 Byte),PRIMARY KEY (TABLE_NAME, ERROR_DESC) ENABLE)";
    stmt = con.createStatement();    
    stmt.execute(strQry);                    

} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Change is just remove the `;` inside " (i.e in the given code it is ENABLE);";

I am changing it to ENABLE)";

Comment: There is no `IF NOT EXISTS` in Oracle